# What is the difference between std::min/std::max and fmin/fmax?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, max, min

In C++, are `std::min` and `std::max` preferable over `fmin` and `fmax`?  For comparing two integers, do they provide basically the same functionality?

Do you tend to use one of these sets of functions or do you prefer to write your own (perhaps to improve efficiency, portability, flexibility, etc.)?

###### *Notes*

1. The C++ Standard Template Library (STL) declares the `min` and `max` functions in the standard C++ [`algorithm`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm) header.
2. The C standard (C99) provides the `fmin` and `fmax` function in the standard C [`math.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math.h) header (also provided in C++11 as `std::fmin` and `std::fmax` in the [`cmath`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath) header).

Answer (score 123, accepted):

`fmin` and `fmax` are specifically for use with floating point numbers (hence the "f"). If you use it for ints, you may suffer performance or precision losses due to conversion, function call overhead, etc. depending on your compiler/platform.

`std::min` and `std::max` are template functions (defined in header [`<algorithm>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm)) which work on any type with a less-than (`<`) operator, so they can operate on any data type that allows such a comparison. You can also provide your own comparison function if you don't want it to work off `<`.

This is safer since you have to explicitly convert arguments to match when they have different types. The compiler won't let you accidentally convert a 64-bit int into a 64-bit float, for example. This reason alone should make the templates your default choice. (Credit to Matthieu M & bk1e)

Even when used with floats the template ***may*** win in performance. A compiler always has the option of inlining calls to template functions since the source code is part of the compilation unit. Sometimes it's *impossible* to inline a call to a library function, on the other hand (shared libraries, absence of link-time optimization, etc.).

Comment: Warning: min and max can only compare two variables of the exact same type... so you can't compare an int and a double with them :(

Comment: True - max(1, 2.0) doesn't work, it has to be something like max<double>(1, 2.0) or max(double(1), 2.0).

Comment: Which is a Good Thing™ IMO :)

Comment: That's a big assumption that there will be a cost for conversion. On some systems the only difference will be loading the values into an FPU Regester rather than a normal register before comparison.

Comment: Well yeah, pretty much every statement about C++ performance depends on the compiler/system. :P I'll change "'ll" to " may"...

Comment: Are there any platforms with 64-bit ints (ILP64) and 64-bit doubles? On those platforms, converting from int to double would result in a loss of precision for extremely positive/negative ints.

Comment: While it's true it may not be possible to inline library functions, it probably is often possible in the case of simple standard functions like fmax. [It's a gcc builtin](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html).

Comment: @bk1e Tho loss off precision would be in both directions.

Answer (score 54):

There is an important difference between `std::min`, `std::max` and `fmin` and `fmax`.

```
std::min(-0.0,0.0) = -0.0
std::max(-0.0,0.0) = -0.0
```

whereas

```
fmin(-0.0, 0.0) = -0.0
fmax(-0.0, 0.0) =  0.0
```

So `std::min` is not a 1-1 substitute for `fmin`. The functions `std::min` and `std::max` are not commutative. To get the same result with doubles with `fmin` and `fmax`, one should swap the arguments

```
fmin(-0.0, 0.0) = std::min(-0.0,  0.0)
fmax(-0.0, 0.0) = std::max( 0.0, -0.0)
```

But as far as I can tell [all these functions are implementation defined anyway in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913952/minimum-and-maximum-of-signed-zero/30914285?noredirect=1#comment49866669_30914285) so to be 100% sure you have to test how they are implemented.

---

There is another important difference. For `x ! = NaN`:

```
std::max(Nan,x) = NaN
std::max(x,NaN) = x
std::min(Nan,x) = NaN
std::min(x,NaN) = x
```

whereas

```
fmax(Nan,x) = x
fmax(x,NaN) = x
fmin(Nan,x) = x
fmin(x,NaN) = x
```

---

`fmax` can be emulated with the following code

```cpp
double myfmax(double x, double y)
{
    // after the next two comparisons, x and y are equivalent or there is NaN
    if(x < y)           return y;
    if(y < x)           return x;
    // z > nan for z != nan is required by C the standard
    if(std::isnan(x))   return y;
    if(std::isnan(y))   return x;
    // +0 > -0 is preferred by C the standard
    if(std::signbit(x)) return y;
    else                return x;
}
```

`std::max` is a subset of `fmax` because it only needs the first comparison (`x < y`).

Looking at the assembly shows that Clang uses builtin code for `fmax` and `fmin` whereas GCC calls them from a math library.  The assembly for clang for `fmax` with `-O3` is

```
movapd  xmm2, xmm0
cmpunordsd      xmm2, xmm2
movapd  xmm3, xmm2
andpd   xmm3, xmm1
maxsd   xmm1, xmm0
andnpd  xmm2, xmm1
orpd    xmm2, xmm3
movapd  xmm0, xmm2
```

whereas for `std::max(double, double)` it is simply

```
maxsd   xmm0, xmm1
```

However, for GCC and Clang using `-Ofast` `fmax` becomes simply

```
maxsd   xmm0, xmm1
```

So this shows once again that `std::max` is a subset of `fmax` and that when you use a looser floating point model which does not have `nan` or signed zero then `fmax` and `std::max` are the same.  The same argument obviously applies to `fmin` and `std::min`.

Comment: The maxsd/minsd instructions comply with fmax, fmin in terms of dropping Nan. But, given two zeros of different signs, they do not select the max or min sign.
However, I can't find any documentation that says fmax,fmin are *defined* to handle zeros in this way. +0 and -0 are generally considered equivalent except where specific behaviour is defined. I believe there's no reason not to use MAXSD for fmax, regardless of -Ofast. 
Also, I think std::max<double> may or may not be mapped to fmax, depending on what headers you've included (thus changing how it treats Nan).

Comment: @greggo, the C standard [states](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#F.10.9.2) " Ideally, fmax would be sensitive to the sign of zero, for example fmax(-0.0, +0.0) would return +0; however, implementation in software might be impractical. ". So it's not a requirement for fmin/fmax but a preference. When I tested these functions they do the preferred thing.

Comment: @greggo, I said this  in my answer. Look at the comments in the code "// z > nan for z != nan is required by C the standard" and "// +0 > -0 is preferred by C the standard ".

Comment: @greggo, I tested your claim that maxsd/minsd drop nan and that's not what I observe http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca78268b6b9f5c88. The operators don't commute just like with signed zero.

Comment: @greggo, here is a better example where I used `_mm_max_sd` which shows that maxsd neither drops nan nor commutes. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/768f6d831e79587f

Comment: I tried both of those on gcc-7.4, get the same results as you: -O2 -ffast-math prints nans, and -O2 by itself doesn't. However, on examining the generated code, I see no execution of the min or max instructions, the compiler is folding the call at compile time (in the second one there is a function with maxsd, but it's not called).

Comment: You're right - If I  break the second one into two C files, so the compiler is forced to call `myfmax`, the result is `-nan 1.000000` regardless of -ffastmath. So, it also seems gcc is not accurately modelling maxsd instruction in compile-time folding, which presumably is considered ok under -ffast-math ...

Comment: OK, it's not quite what I said for the second one. Without -ffast-math, it inlines the fmax into main, and actually does the 0.0/0.0 with a divsd and it gives `-nan 1.000000`. With -ffast-math it just works it all out at compile time and gives `nan nan`

Answer (score 18):

You're missing the entire point of fmin and fmax. It was included in C99 so that modern CPUs could use their native (read SSE) instructions for floating point min and max and avoid a test and branch (and thus a possibly mis-predicted branch). I've re-written code that used std::min and std::max to use SSE intrinsics for min and max in inner loops instead and the speed-up was significant.

Comment: How big was the speedup? Why can't the C++ compiler detect when you're using std::min<double>?

Comment: Perhaps he did not have optimization turned on when he tested, or else the compiler was trying to compile a binary that could run 'anywhere' and thus didn't know it could use SSE. I suspect that using gcc, the differences would disappear if you passed the flags `-O3 -march=native`

Comment: The real reason it was included in C was because C does not have templates or function overloading, so they to create a differently-named function than just max for floating-point types.

Comment: just tried this on g++4.8: fmax, `std::max<double>`  and even `(a>b)?a:b` all map to a single maxsd instruction on at -O1. (so you get different treatment of NaNs than at  -O0...)

Answer (score 6):

std::min and std::max are templates. So, they can be used on a variety of types that provide the less than operator, including floats, doubles, long doubles. So, if you wanted to write generic C++ code you'd do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
T const& max3(T const& a, T const& b, T const& c)
{
   using std::max;
   return max(max(a,b),c); // non-qualified max allows ADL
}
```

As for performance, I don't think `fmin` and `fmax` differ from their C++ counterparts.

Comment: What is ADL, and why do we want it here?

Comment: ADL = argument dependent lookup. In this case it is probably not necessary because every user-defined type that comes with its own max-function is likely to provide a special less than operator as well. It's just a habit of mine that I write code like this -- primarily with `swap` and some numerical functions like `abs`. You would *want* to use a type's special swap and abs functions instead of the generic ones in case the special ones exist. I suggest reading Herb Sutter's article about "namespaces and the interface principle": http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill08.htm

Answer (score 6):

If your implementation provides a 64-bit integer type, you may get a different (incorrect) answer by using fmin or fmax. Your 64-bit integers will be converted to doubles, which will (at least usually) have a significand that's smaller than 64-bits. When you convert such a number to a double, some of the least significant bits can/will be lost completely.

This means that two numbers that were really different could end up equal when converted to double -- and the result will be that incorrect number, that's not necessarily equal to either of the original inputs.

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer the C++ min/max functions, if you are using C++, because they are type-specific.  fmin/fmax will force everything to be converted to/from floating point.

Also, the C++ min/max functions will work with user-defined types as long as you have defined operator< for those types.

HTH

Answer (score 3):

As Richard Corden pointed, use C++ functions min and max defined in std namespace. They provide type safety, and help to avoid comparing mixed types (i.e. float point vs integer) what sometimes may be undesirable.

If you find that C++ library you use defines min/max as macros as well, it may cause conflicts, then you can prevent unwanted macro substitution calling the min/max functions this way (notice extra brackets):

```
(std::min)(x, y)
(std::max)(x, y)
```

Remember, this will effectively disable [Argument Dependant Lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_dependent_name_lookup) (ADL, also called Koenig lookup), in case you want to rely on ADL.

Answer (score 2):

As you noted yourself, `fmin` and `fmax` were introduced in C99. Standard C++ library doesn't have `fmin` and `fmax` functions. Until C99 standard library gets incorporated into C++ (if ever), the application areas of these functions are cleanly separated. There's no situation where you might have to "prefer" one over the other.

You just use templated `std::min`/`std::max` in C++, and use whatever is available in C.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, in `cstdlib` there are `__min` and `__max` you can use.

For more:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/btkhtd8d.aspx

Comment: There is no reason to use these macros in C++, and arguably no reason to use them in C either. Just use `std::min` and `std::max`.

Answer (score 0):

fmin and fmax are only for floating point and double variables.

min and max are template functions that allow comparison of any types, given a binary predicate. They can also be used with other algorithms to provide complex functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::min` and `std::max`.

If the other versions are faster then your implementation can add overloads for these and you'll get the benefit of performance and portability:

```
template <typename T>
T min (T, T) {
  // ... default
}

inline float min (float f1, float f2) {
 return fmin( f1, f2);
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. `std::min` and `std::fmin` have different treatment of NaN and possibly different treatment of negative/positive zero. `std::min` cannot be implemented in terms of `std::fmin` if this is faster.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this @JanSchultke.  Can you elaborate on exactly why an implementation cannot use `fmin`?

Comment: Because `std::min` (https://eel.is/c++draft/alg.min.max#2) returns the "smaller" of the two values, or the first if they're equivalent. `std::fmin(NaN, x)` returns `x` even though `NaN` is neither smaller nor equivalent to `x`, though this coincidentally matches `std::min(NaN, x)`. `std::fmin(x, NaN)` returns `x` even though `x` is uncomparable to (neither equivalent nor less than) `NaN`. `std::fmin(0, -0)` is encouraged to be zero-sign-aware and return `-0` even though `0 == -0` and `!(0 < -0)` are true.

Comment: The NaN cases are actually fine though. I believe `std::min` with NaN is simply undefined behavior and if the result was `std::fmin` in such case, this would comply with the standard. The actual standard-compliance problem is violating the usual behavior of `std::min` for the sake of having a "lower" or "greater" zero sign.

Comment: Thanks for the detail.   Would floating point values not have an issue with "the usual behaviour" for many other cases too?  (i.e for the same reason that in general floats shouldn't be compared with == )?

Comment: No, comparing floats with `<` or `>` is perfectly precise and usually not a problem. The only issue arises at `0` and `-0` because they compare equal but are distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't a C++ implementation targeted for processors with SSE instructions provide specializations of **std::min** and **std::max** for types **float**, **double**, and **long double** which do the equivalent of **fminf**, **fmin**, and **fminl**, respectively?

The specializations would provide better performance for floating-point types while the general template would handle non-floating-point types without attempting to coerce floating-point types into floating-point types that way the **fmin**s and **fmax**es would.

Comment: Intel c++ has better performance for std::min than fmin. In gcc, good performance  of fmin requires finite-math-only setting which breaks it for non-finite operands.

Comment: No, they could not. `std::min` and `std::fmin` handle NaNs and possibly zeros differently, so `std::min` cannot simply do what `std::fmin` does. However, `std::min` compiles to just a single MAXSS instruction on x86.

Answer (score 0):

In short, `std::max` is a "generic function" from the `<algotithm>` library that simply chooses the lower of two arguments according to the `<` operator, whereas `std::fmax` is specific to floating-point numbers and treats NaN as missing data.

### `std::fmax`/`std::fmin`

> The contents and meaning of the header `<cmath>` are the same as the C standard library header `<math.h>` [...]

- [C++23 standard : [cmath.syn] p1](https://eel.is/c++draft/cmath.syn#1)

> If just one argument is a `NaN`, the `fmax` functions return the other argument (if both arguments are `NaN`s, the functions return a `NaN`).
> [...]
> The body of the `fmax` function might be
>
> ```cpp
> { return (isgreaterequal(x, y) || isnan(y)) ? x : y; }
> ```

- [C17 standard: F.10.9.2 The fmax functions](https://cigix.me/c17#F.10.9.2)

It's also worth noting that `fmax`/`fmin` may be sensitive to the sign of zero:

> Ideally, `fmax` would be sensitive to the sign of zero, for example `fmax(−0.0, +0.0)` would return `+0`; however, implementation in software might be impractical.

- [C17 standard: footnote 380](https://cigix.me/c17#footnote380)

### `std::max`/`std::min`

> ```cpp
> template<class T>
> constexpr const T& max(const T& a, const T& b);
> // [...]
> ```
>
> *Preconditions:* For the first form, T meets the *Cpp17LessThanComparable* requirements (Table [29](https://eel.is/c++draft/utility.arg.requirements#tab:cpp17.lessthancomparable)).
>
> *Returns:* The larger value. Returns the first argument when the arguments are equivalent.

- [[alg.min.max] `std::max`](https://eel.is/c++draft/alg.min.max#lib:max)

There is no sample implementation in the standard, but a possible implementation looks like:

```cpp
{ return a < b ? b : a; }
```

### Which one to choose

For performance reasons, it is better to use `std::max` and `std::min`.
On modern x86_64, `std::max` compiles to a single instruction

```
vmaxss  xmm0, xmm1, xmm0            ; xmm0 = max(xmm1, xmm0)
```

... whereas `std::fmax` compiles to

```
vmaxss      xmm2, xmm1, xmm0        ; xmm2 = max(xmm1, xmm0)
vcmpunordss xmm0, xmm0, xmm0        ; test xmm0 for NaN, set mask bits
vblendvps   xmm0, xmm2, xmm1, xmm0  ; xmm0 = isnan(xmm0) ? xmm1 : xmm2
```

See [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/jvYGrdfhY).

If there's no possibility of operands being NaN, you should go for `std::max`/`std::min`. Otherwise, use `std::fmax`/`std::fmin`.

#### Further Notes on Assembly

`std::fmax(x, y)` cannot be implemented using only `vmaxss dest, y, x` because if `x` or `y` is NaN, `dest = x`. `std::fmax` chooses `x` or `y` depending on which one isn't NaN. `vmaxss` is biased towards `x` in every possible way.

However, `vmaxss` matches the behavior of `x < y ? y : x` and thus `std::max` exactly.

Answer (score -1):

I always use the min and max macros for ints.  I'm not sure why anyone would use fmin or fmax for integer values.

The big gotcha with min and max is that they're not functions, even if they look like them.  If you do something like:

```
min (10, BigExpensiveFunctionCall())
```

That function call may get called twice depending on the implementation of the macro.  As such, its best practice in my org to never call min or max with things that aren't a literal or variable.

Comment: min and max are often implemented as macros in C, but this is C++, where they're implemented as templates.  Much, much better.

Comment: If you `#include <windows.h>`, you get `min` and `max` defined as macros.  This will conflict with `std::min` and `std::max`, so you need to compile your sources with `#define NOMINMAX` to exclude the former.

Comment: It would have been nice if Microsoft put a `#ifdef _WINDOWS #undef min` in their `<algorithm>` header. Saves me the effort

Comment: @MSalters: Good idea, however this is not the standard library's responsibility. They shouldn't have polluted the namespace with such common names instead.

Comment: There is a weird gotcha with `std::min`: it actually accepts two const references, and returns one of them. Usually, that gets folded by the compiler. But I once had a `std::min( x, constval)`, where `constval` was defined as `static const int constval=10;` in the class. And, I got a link error: `undefined MyClass::constval`. Since, now the constval has to exist, since a reference to it is being taken. Can be fixed by using `std::min( x, constval+0)`

Answer (score -1):

`fmin` and `fmax`, of `fminl` and `fmaxl` could be preferred when comparing signed and unsigned integers - you can take advantage of the fact that the entire range of signed and unsigned numbers and you don't have to worry about integer ranges and promotions.

```
unsigned int x = 4000000000;
int y = -1;

int z = min(x, y);
z = (int)fmin(x, y);
```

Comment: why aren't there specializations that handle these cases?

Answer (score -1):

The key difference is in the types of values they operate on. `std::min` and `std::max` are more general and can be used with various data types, while `fmin` and `fmax` are specifically designed for floating-point numbers. If you are working with integers or other types, you should use `std::min` and `std::max`.

Comment: There are numerous answers to this question already and many of them point out the difference(s) that you have noted in your answer. What does this add that is not already stated in other answers?