# What function(s) determine the max or min of two integers?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, max, min

Which _STD function(s) return the max, or min of 2 integers, signed or unsigned? Is it the max, min in the math.h header library or what could they be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of min and max functions in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632145/use-of-min-and-max-functions-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::min` and `std::max` in the `<algorithm>` library. As they're templates they return the min and max for every type that implements the `<` operator (or you can supply a functor for your custom comparison).

See [Algorithms library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) (link to cppreference.com).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the new algorithm introduced in C++11(

```
 template<class T> pair<const T&, const T&> minmax(const T& a, const T& b);
```

> Returns: pair(b, a) if b is smaller than a, and
>        pair(a, b) otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

`std::max` and `std::min` are in the file `algorithm`.

You can look up the other functions included in this file at [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/). Bookmark it for future usage.