# Why the global variable gets doubled twice?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define abs(x) (x < 0 ? -x : x)
int x;
int doubleGlobalX()
{
    x*=2;
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    scanf("%d",&x);//5
    printf("%d\n",abs(doubleGlobalX()));//20
    return 0;
}
```

When the input is `5` the output of this code is `20`. When input is `15` the output is `60`. Don't know why it doubles the global twice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is double evaluation and why should it be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39439181/what-is-double-evaluation-and-why-should-it-be-avoided)

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%d",&x);`  The `scanf()` family of functions returns the number of successful 'input conversion specifiers'  (in this case any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred.

Comment: OT: regarding: `#define abs(x) (x < 0 ? -x : x)`  Always place parens around the parameter in the result statement to avoid 'text replacement' errors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#define abs(x) (x < 0 ? -x : x)
```

Macros perform textual substitution. Defining an `abs()` macro like this is a well-known trap because it ends up evaluating `x` twice. If it were a function it'd be fine, but as a macro it's a problem. `abs(doubleGlobalX())` expands to:

```
doubleGlobalX() < 0 ? -doubleGlobalX() : doubleGlobalX()
```

It ends up calling `doubleGlobalX()` twice which causes `x` to be doubled twice.

Comment: Macros substitute preprocessor tokens, not text. These are different; one consequence is that macro replacement cannot form new preprocessor tokens (without the `##` operator), whereas text replacement could.

Comment: The problem is not the language used. The problem is the statement is false and gives people incorrect information.