# What's wrong with f(random(..), random(..)) in C?

Tags: c, random, function-definition

I came across a problem which really confused me. 
I was trying to calculate the values of `f(x,y) = (y^3)/(x^2+y^2)` at some random points on `-1 < x < 1` and `-1 < y < 1`.

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

#define f(x, y) ( pow((y),3) / (pow((x),2) + pow((y),2)) )

double random(double min, double max)
{
    double m;
    m = rand()/(double)RAND_MAX;
    return (min + m * (max - min));
}

void main()
{
    int i; 
    double v;
    
    for(i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        v = f(random(-1,1), random(-1,1));
        printf("%lf\n", s);
    }
}
```

And then i got some very weird values which are greater than 1 or smaller than -1 (which are the maximum and minimum f can get on -1<x<1 and -1<y<1).

On the other hand, when i changed my code by using 2 variables carrying random x and y and then plug them into f:

```
    double x, y;
    for(i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        x = random(-1,1);
        y = random(-1,1);
        v = f(x, y);
        printf("%lf\n", s);
    }
```

the problem disappeard. 
Can anyone please help me explain this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the first, the `y` expression has two different values. In the second, `y` is the same value. If you expand the macro, you will see.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39439181/what-is-double-evaluation-and-why-should-it-be-avoided - avoid macros when a plain function is sufficient.

Comment: Rewrite `f()` as a function, and your problem will go away.

Comment: ...it expands to `( pow((random(-1,1)),3) / (pow((random(-1,1)),2) + pow((random(-1,1)),2)) )`. You have called `random` three times, but in the second example you call `random` twice. So they aren't the same.

Answer (score 2):

In the first example:

```c
f(random(-1, 1), random(-1, 1));
```

will be:

```c
(pow((random(-1, 1)),3) / (pow((random(-1, 1)),2) + pow((random(-1, 1)),2)))
```

As you can see: `random(-1, 1)` in `(pow((random(-1, 1)),3)` will not equal to
`random(-1, 1)` in `pow((random(-1, 1)),2))`, although you want it to be the same value.

But in the second example:

```c
f(x, y);
```

will be:

```c
( pow((y),3) / (pow((x),2) + pow((y),2)) )
```

which `y` in `pow((y),3)` is equal to `y` in `pow((y),2)`, cause they have the same value

Don't use macro. Instead, use a function:

```c
#define f(x, y) ( pow((y),3) / (pow((x),2) + pow((y),2)) )
```

to

```
double f(double x, double y)
{
    return pow((y),3) / (pow((x),2) + pow((y),2));
}
```