# Why does Release/Debug have a different result for std::min?

Tags: c++, nan, min, floating-point-comparison

Here is the test program:

```
void testFunc()
{
    double maxValue = DBL_MAX;
    double slope = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();

    std::cout << "slope is " << slope << std::endl;
    std::cout << "maxThreshold is " << maxValue << std::endl;
    std::cout << "the_min is " << std::min( slope, maxValue) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "the_min is " << std::min( DBL_MAX, std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()) << std::endl;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    testFunc();
    return 0;
}
```

In Debug, I get:

```
slope is nan
maxThreshold is 1.79769e+308
the_min is nan
the_min is 1.79769e+308
```

In Release, I get:

```
slope is nan
maxThreshold is 1.79769e+308
the_min is 1.79769e+308
the_min is nan
```

Why would I get a different result in Release than Debug?

I already checked Stack Overflow post *[Use of min and max functions in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632145/use-of-min-and-max-functions-in-c)*, and it  does not mention any Release/Debug differences.

I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I think the problem is not with `std::min`, it's with `std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()`

Comment: I remember the 64-bit version of `cl` having problems with correct `NaN` handling in Release mode, but that was in VS 2008. I would hope they fixed it since then.

Comment: I am not sure `NaN` will fit in `LessThanComparable`

Comment: I suppose both behaviors are valid because the actual representation of nan is implementation defined. You shouldn't ever compare against nan, even with another nan.

Comment: For GCC you can set `-frounding-math -fsignaling-nans` on the compiler so that it guarantees strict IEEE 754 compliance. That way it should never re-order comparisons (or any other optimisations) which might change behaviour due to NaN. For Visual Studio, `/fp:precise` appears to be the equivalent (which promises not to optimise things such as x-x=0).

Comment: @Dave: `/fp:precise` is enabled by default and this does not prevent Debug behaviour to be different than Release...

Comment: In that case I can only assume it's a bug / missing feature in the implementation, since they mention that the option is explicitly to enable correct handling of NaN (my suspicion is that a compiler optimisation stage hasn't been properly flagged; maybe raise a bug?). I see that there is also `/fp:strict`, which may also be worth a shot (but potentially incurs a lot of overhead).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Got it:

Here is the implementation used by VS in Debug mode (with `_Pred` being `DEBUG_LT`, LT for Lower Than):

```
template<class _Pr,
    class _Ty1,
    class _Ty2> inline
    _CONST_FUN bool _Debug_lt_pred(_Pr _Pred,
        _Ty1&& _Left, _Ty2&& _Right,
        _Dbfile_t _File, _Dbline_t _Line)
    {   // test if _Pred(_Left, _Right) and _Pred is strict weak ordering
    return (!_Pred(_Left, _Right)
        ? false
        : _Pred(_Right, _Left)
            ? (_DEBUG_ERROR2("invalid comparator", _File, _Line), true)
            : true);
    }
```

Which is equivalent to (more readable):

```
    if (!_Pred(_Left, _Right))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if ( _Pred(_Right, _Left) )
        {
            assert( false );
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Which, again is equivalent to `(!_Pred(_Left, _Right))`. Transcripted as a macro, it becomes `#define _DEBUG_LT(x, y)   !((y) < (x))` (i.e: NOT right < left).

Release implementation is actually a macro `#define _DEBUG_LT(x, y) ((x) < (y))` (i.e: left < right).

So Debug `(!(y<x))` and Release `(x<y)` implementations are definitely not the same and they do behave differently if one parameter is a NaN...! Don't ask why they did that....

Comment: Nice sleuthing.

Comment: Well, they did it to catch bugs. In debug builds, it evaluates the expression both ways, and asserts that they produce the same answer. In release builds, you assume that the app has been debugged and the comparators are correct, so you don't want to pay the penalty of doing two comparisons.

Comment: Sure, but at least, they could have make sure that both end up with the same result....that would have been possible by checking both ways in a different order.

Answer (score 39):

In [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) comparing NAN to anything will always yield `false`, no matter what it is.

```
slope > 0; // false
slope < 0; // false
slope == 0; // false
```

And, more importantly for you

```
slope < DBL_MAX; // false
DBL_MAX < slope; // false
```

So it seems that the compiler reorders the parameters/uses `>` or `<=` instead of `<`, and that's why you get the differing results.

For example, those functions could be described as such

Release:

```
double const& min(double const& l, double const r) {
    return l <= r ? l : r;
}
```

Debug:

```
double const& min(double const& l, double const& r) {
    return r < l ? r : l;
}
```

The requirements (LessThanComparable) on `std::min` aside, those have the same meaning arithmetically. But they yield different results when you use them with NaN.

Comment: An additional point to whoever might be interested: In IEEE754 comparing NAN to anything _including itself_ will always yield `false`.  BTW, [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034149/why-is-nan-not-equal-to-nan) was well-posed and has an interesting set of answers - including several quite amusing catfights in the comments.

Comment: I was about to comment that "anything" includes false, but when I checked NaN ∈ anything I got `false`.

Comment: @krzaq Try checking NaN ∉ anything instead.

Comment: @krzaq shouldn't it rather swap the `r : l` than the `r < l`, since otherwise it still evaluates to false and `l` is returned? I.e. `r < l ? r : l;` -> `r > l ? l : r;`

Comment: Something is definitely wrong. I'll have to wrap my head around this, because it also has to fit *Remarks: Returns the first argument when the arguments are equivalent.* both times.

Comment: @tkausl would you mind looking at it now? I think it's correct and true to the example now.

Comment: Looks better, yes.

Answer (score 23):

You didn't specify which floating point representation format your processor uses. But, since you use Visual Studio, I'll assume that you use Windows, and then I'll assume that your processor uses [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) representation.

In IEEE 754, NaN is unordered in respect to every number. This means that `(NaN < f) == false` and `(f < NaN) == false` for any value of `f`. Pedantically, this means that floating point numbers that support NaN do not meet the requirements of [LessThanComparable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/LessThanComparable) which is a requirement for `std::min`. Practically `std::min` behaves as specified in the standard as long as neither argument is NaN.

Since one of the arguments is NaN in your code, the result is unspecified by the standard - it could be one or the other depending on any external factors such as release vs debug build, version of compiler, phase of the moon, etc.

Comment: It looks to me like floating-point numbers satisfy all requirements of LessThanComparable. LessThanComparable doesn't require a total order; it only requires a strict weak ordering. The fact that any comparison involving NaN returns false doesn't violate any requirements. (This is all ignoring signalling NaNs, any use of which is UB.)

Comment: @user2357112 upon further inspection of the rules, I think that you are indeed correct. I shall fix the answer.

Comment: Wait, what the - actually, it looks like the *cppreference page* is wrong, and it's been missing one of the strict weak ordering requirements for years: defining `equiv(a, b)` as `!(a < b) && !(b < a)`, it is required that `equiv(a, b) && equiv(b, c)` implies `equiv(a, c)`. NaN violates that requirement, so it looks like floating-point numbers really don't satisfy LessThanComparable.