# Attributes and default function arguments

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++14, deprecated

I am needing to upgrade some legacy code to no longer rely on global variables.  A pattern I am finding is something like:

```cpp
int foo() { 
  int i = some_number_from_hyperspace(); // Thread-safety problems
  return i * 42; 
}
```

Whereas the better approach would be

```cpp
int foo(int i) { 
  return i * 42; 
}
```

and to deprecate the `some_number_from_hyperspace` function.  The way I would prefer to deprecate, while keeping things maintainable, is to use the following idiom:

```cpp
[[deprecated]] int some_number_from_hyperspace();

int foo(int i = some_number_from_hyperspace()) {
  return i * 42;
}
foo(); // Deprecation warning
foo(2); // No warning
```

This pattern appears to work for MSVC 19.22, however, neither GCC 9.2 or Clang 8 appear to support it.  Feel free to experiment:

https://godbolt.org/z/LWCghE

As much as I like the MSVC behavior, the code must be supported by GCC and Clang.  I'm guessing that the timing of when attributes are applied depends on the implementation.  Am I right?  Any other suggestions about how to approach this problem?

Comment: You may be experiencing a standard selection issue or an old compiler issue:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39956021. When I try clang++ v7 it likes `[[deprecated]]` with `--std=c++14`, and g++ v8.2 will accept it unless you specify a pretty early `--std`.

Comment: @dmckee clang 8 and gcc 9.2 [both warn on `--std=c++17`](https://godbolt.org/z/ice7wA)

Comment: @Artyer Thanks.  I confirm that, and the required standard is c++17.

Comment: `[[deprecated]]` doesn't exist in C++11.  Please update the tag.

Comment: @Artyer: but they warn on default argument even if not called. whereas msvc only warns when it is actually called. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/wY-xAx)

Comment: Unrelated: If it's not too much work you could also put the deprecated stuff in a namespace of its own to make it pop out when debugging etc: [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/Z2z5t2)

Comment: The link you provide seems to show the same warnings from all three compilers (although GCC emits them twice for some reason).