# Are rvalue references Cpp17MoveConstructible?

Tags: c++, reference, language-lawyer, swap, rvalue-reference

Do rvalue references satisfy the [*Cpp17MoveConstructible*](https://eel.is/c++draft/utility.arg.requirements#tab:cpp17.moveconstructible) requirement?

For this to be the case, in the expression `T u = rv;`, `u` would need to be "equivalent" to `rv`. If `T` was an rvalue reference (e.g. `int&&`), then in `int&& u = 0;`, `u` would need to be "equivalent" to `0`. However, is a reference ever equivalent to a value, or does it merely refer to an object which is equivalent?

#### Motivation

The reason I'm asking is because it's unclear to me how [`std::swap<int&&>`](https://eel.is/c++draft/utility.swap#lib:swap) *should* behave.

`is_move_constructible_v<int&&>` and `is_move_assignable_v<int&&>` are true, so the constraints of `std::swap` are satisifed and it can be instantiated.
However, the effect of `swap<int&&>` is undefined if `int&&` does not satisfy *Cpp17MoveConstructible*.

In fact, all major implementations (libc++, libstdc++, MSVC STL) implement `std::swap(a, b)` along the lines of:

```cpp
T t = std::move(a);
a = std::move(b);
b = std::move(t);
```

If `T` is an rvalue reference, then `T t = _MOVE(a)` is not creating a move-constructed copy, but binding an rvalue reference to another rvalue reference.
For `T = int&&`, the effect is then equivalent to:

```cpp
a = a;
b = a;
```

What do we make of this?

- Rvalue references do not satisfy *Cpp17MoveConstructible*. All implementations are correct. The preconditions of `swap` are not satisfied so it can be have like this.
- Rvalue references satisfy *Cpp17MoveConstructible*. All implementations are wrong.

Well, which is it?

---

*Note*: Issue [LWG4047](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue4047) "Explicitly specifying template arguments for `std::swap` should not be supported" addresses some of the concerns here.

Comment: rvalue references are lvalues

Comment: Also you are missing that the object is required to be move assignable and reference are not assignable.  I feel it should be constructible as reference members do not prevent constructors from being created but as you point out moving or copying doesn't do anything as the reference just refers to whatever the other reference refers to.

Comment: Question is _MOVE different from std::move? If not use std::move in your example now  I can only assume what _MOVE does. I also think move does `T&& t= std::move(t);` which is enough to extend the lifetime for the duration of the scope.

Comment: @NathanOliver rvalue references satisfy the `is_move_assignable<T>` constraint, and the same issue of equivalence pops when when looking at *[Cpp17MoveAssignable](https://eel.is/c++draft/tab:cpp17.moveassignable)*.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I thought that it would have different semantics than `std::move` because of ADL, but `std::move` is not unqualified so that wouldn't be an issue here. I guess we can specify it in terms of that. In fact, libc++ does exactly that, but libstdc++ uses `_GLIBCXX_MOVE`.

Comment: There are no rvalues of reference type, so *Cpp17MoveConstructible* would be vacuously satisfied for reference types. This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/55153210/5754656 because the operations are "for all `rv`" instead of having a precondition on the specific rvalue expressions being used in `swap`.

Comment: @Artyer I think you've hit the nail on the head. If rvalue references vacuously satisfy the constraint, then the preconditions and constraints are satisfied. All implementations are wrong then.

Comment: @JanSchultke I think I am missing something about the domain of values for `rv`, since this reading implies that `int` is not Cpp17MoveConstructible since with `int x;`, the xvalue `std::move(x)` does not satisfy the postcondition for `int u = std::move(x)` (which is UB instead of making `u` equivalent to `x`)

Comment: @Artyer I struggle to see the wording same as you. `rv` is specified to be an rvalue of type `T` above, which would be an rvalue of type `int`. It doesn't matter whether `rv` is an xvalue or prvalue, when we do `int u = rv`, `u` is equivalent to the value of `rv` before construction. I don't know why you think that this would be UB. `int x = 0` and `int x = static_cast<int&&>(0)` are both valid and satisfy the postcondition. There is no such thing as an rvalue of type `int&&` though, so these constraints are vacuously satisfied. It makes sense.

Comment: @JanSchultke In this case because `x` wasn't initialized. This is also an issue for prvalues with trap representation (that you can get with `std::bit_cast<int>(char_array_of_trap_repr)`)

Comment: @Artyer I don't think that trap representations are relevant here. "trap representations" simply aren't valid values in C++, so the requirements only apply to `int x = rv` when `rv` is a value. Everything seems okay. Also, why wouldn't `x` be initialized? This statement is doing copy-initialization. Maybe you're misreading the requirement. "Before the construction" refers to `x`, so after construction of `x`, `x` must be equivalent to the value `rv` had before. In `int x = 0;`, `x` will be initialized to the value that `0` had prior to construction of `x`.

Comment: @JanSchultke I'm saying if this were a "for all" requirement, the xvalue `std::move(x)` where `x` is defined `int x;` and not initialized, `int u = rv` (`rv` is the rvalue `std::move(x)`)), would not satisfy the postconditions. So I'm just assuming I'm missing something that limits what `rv` can be. It would be useful to say `int x; int y = 0; std::swap(x, y);` is undefined behaviour, but whatever makes that UB would also make `std::swap<int&&>(0, 0)` undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Artyer yeah I see now. The description above should probably constrain `rv` so that it's not an arbitrary rvalue, but one which denotes an (initialized) object. You're technically right but this also means that literally no type satisfies *Cpp17MoveConstructible*. I don't think you're missing something about `rv`; instead, I think this is a LWG oversight. Or perhaps, there is some over-arching paragraph that says that the lvalues and rvalues in these descriptions refer to initialized objects, but I'm not aware of such a paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

> Are rvalue references *Cpp17MoveConstructible*?

No one knows, not even the committee.

This question has first been asked in [LWG2146](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2146) *Are reference types `Copy`/`Move-Constructible`/`Assignable` or `Destructible`?*, in March 2012.

It is an open issue with no clear consensus, and the exact same concern about explicitly calling e.g. `std::swap<int&&>(x, y)` or `std::for_each<int*, F&&>` gets brought up in this issue.
Some of these problems have since been solved, namely:

- The `std::for_each` case is banned as per [[algorithms.requirements] p15](https://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.requirements#15) (calling algorithms with explicitly-specified template arguments is unspecified behavior).
- The `std::thread` constructor was fixed through use of `decay_t`.

However: **"The swap case still needs solving. Still need a survey."**